# Deleting scheduled items in the Publish Queue not cleaning up properly

Tags: publishing, publishtransaction, 2013-sp1-hr1

Scenario (confirmed in a client environment and our dev instance):

- publish content with

  - render now
  - deploy later
- wait for item to complete rendering
- delete item from Publish Queue (before publish time expires)

At this point I would expect the reference to be removed both from the Publishing Queue and the deployment package from the \temp or \deployer filestore

- Refresh the Publish Queue
- Note the item has now progressed to the next phase and not actually removed

  .
- Delete *one more* from the Publish Queue
- note the item has now been removed from the Publish Queue

**BUT**, on checking the *incoming folder* I can see that the `.wait` version of the deployment package is not cleaned up.

- we did wait for the publish time to expire and observed that the package did *not* deploy - but I'm still nervous having this physically sticking around.

Is there a hotfix to address this - I've looked through but I can't see anything that sticks out (we're already on HR1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing as an answer as it will be huge comment! We raised this with Tridion Support (in Feb 2016) and this is the exact response we got:

"
After some investigation, I came to find out that this issue was a known product defect.  It has been reported from other customer as well.  However, Development considers it to not be highly critical as this issue does not lead to any inconsistent data, but to a wrong feedback instead in the UI.

The problem does not affect data published so it will not be hotfixed.  But it will be fixed in a future release

The 'workaround' which is to delete the items twice. There is currently a request that was submitted to have this fixed in the next Tridion release.
"

Comment: This looks fine as an answer. No reason why it should be a comment.

Comment: This is NOT the answer I WANTED. But, as Dom noted - this IS an answer and it's very useful so thank Vipin!!! Answer +1 !